# lua_next segfault on LUA_ENVIRONINDEX?

Tags: lua

The following C program that uses the Lua API `lua_next` function to try and begin iterating LUA_ENVIRONINDEX table crashes in call to `lua_next`...

```
#include <lua5.1/lua.hpp>

int main() {
  lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();
  lua_pushnil(L);
  lua_next(L, LUA_ENVIRONINDEX);
}
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

The [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-LUA_ENVIRONINDEX) says that `LUA_ENVIRONINDEX` "gives the environment of the running C function". In your code, there is no "running C function" in the sense of Lua: `main` was not called from Lua.

Take `lua.c`. If you put your code in `main`, then there is a crash, as you have found out. If you put your code in `pmain`, which is called from Lua, then there is no crash.